# anyone want to help out?

Tags: discussion

I have to the best of my abilities tried to manage both of our Facebook and Google+ pages.  Tamer Shlash is also helping, but he has from what I understand limited internet access.  I could not access our facebook page for a while, but we resolved it another way and now I have access.  I personally have work and study to do.  And when I get time to answer questions on Islam.SE, which is a lot of time these days, I post posts on Google+ page.  But since I now have access to the facebook page again, it is hard for me to manage both in a proper way.

What I am looking for is someone who can help posting on our Google+ page and manage it, all that needs to be done is post questions from here on there, and Meta posts as well.  Also what needs to be done, is to post the same posts on the Google+ community that the page manages (Google+ has a new feature out called "Communities" so I tried it out, and have a community along with the page, it is kind of like a forum)  So can anyone volunteer to help out? the one who volunteers will be added as a manager to our Google+ page.  Thank you.